# When and who should set a feature to "done" in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We use Azure DevOps with the Scrum template to manage our product backlog.
For each change request our customer asks for, we create a new feature with underlying PBIs (product backlog items) and tasks. Our developers set the PBIs to "done" as soon as the PBI passes the pull request.

At the moment we don't have a standard that defines

1. When the feature should be set to "done". That could be

- as soon as all PBIs of the feature are set to "done"
- as soon as the feature is deployed to the production environment
- etc.

2. Who is responsible for changing the status. That could be

- the product owner
- the developer that executes the deployment
- etc.

How do you manage the feature status in your teams?

Answer (score 0):

Answers will be somewhat opinion-based, but where I work it's typically the responsibility of the person who raised the feature to close it down. Only they can decide if the development team has met all of the acceptance criteria.

QA may say "we've tested it, we're happy to ship it", but there may be some child items under the feature which are follow-up activities (documentation, customer comms, website updates, support might want to do deployment tests into a cloud platform...) which need to be completed before the feature is "done".